# how to render img by filereader and push img arr to obj

Tags: javascript

What I'm trying to do is to get an image from my input type="file" and do a card with this image and other information from inputs type="text".

The problem is that whenever I store an image src data in variable and push it to array of imgArrForPush (that is array for extra pictures that admin wants to see on other page after you click on card) and it works but when I'm trying to add imgArrForPush in object to push all of data to cardArr (cardArr is arr that store all card's information in object and I want to render this data) it doesn't work, what I receive is undefined.

The error:

> undefined:1 GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/undefined 404 (Not Found)

I don't think that css of the whole page play a big role in that problem so I created another folder and trying to solve this problem with this styles. But I think that css of a card would be important.
I'm also using fontawesome icons and I don't know is it ok that icons is here in code.

```html
 <div class="admin-inputs-container">
        <input type="file" class="input">
        <button class="admin-buttons" onclick="onGetImg()">submit</button>

  
        <input class="admin-inputs img-name-input" type="text" placeholder="img name(must be number)" />
    
   
        <input class="admin-inputs district-input" type="text" placeholder="district"/>
   
   
        <input class="admin-inputs area-input" type="text" placeholder="area"/>
    
  
        <input class="admin-inputs rooms-input" type="text" placeholder="number of rooms"/>
    
        <input class="admin-inputs floor-input" type="text" placeholder="floor"/>
    
   
        <input class="admin-inputs number-of-floors-input" type="text" placeholder="floors in building"/>
    
  
        <input class="admin-inputs price-input" type="text" placeholder="price"/>
    
 
        <input class="admin-inputs adress-input" type="text" placeholder="adreess"/> 
    
    <div class="admin-inputs-container">
        <button class="admin-buttons" onclick="onGetDataFromInput()">submit</button>
    </div>

<button onclick="redner()">render</button>

<div class="container"></div>
```

```css
.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 40%;
  align-items: flex-start;
  border: 4px solid #0A3D33;
  margin: 0 0 30px 0;
}

.card-button {
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #f4f3f0;
  color: #0A3D33;
  border: 2px solid #0A3D33;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 150px;
}

.card-button:hover {
  background-color:  #0A3D33 ;
  color: #f4f3f0;
}

.card-button:active {
  background-color: #E7E6E3;
  color: #0A3D33;
}


.card-info-container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.card-info-sign-container {
  border-top: 2px solid #0A3D33;
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}

.icon-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
}

.card-info-price-container {
  border-top: 2px solid #0A3D33;
  gap: 5px;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 70px;
}

.card-info-sign {
  font-size: 36px;
}

.card-price {
  font-size: 36px;
}

.card-img {
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card-icon-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 25px;
}

.fa-arrow-up,
.fa-bed,
.fa-layer-group,
.fa-location-dot {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.fa-dollar-sign {
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #137A63;
}

.fa-location-dot {
  color: #c85108;
}

.fa-layer-group {
  color: #a20e0e;
}

.fa-arrow-up {
  color: #318CE7;
}

.password-input { 
  width: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #f4f3f0;
  border: 2px solid #0A3D33;
  color: #0A3D33;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.wirte-a-password-sign{
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #0A3D33;
}

.admin-inputs {
  width: 320px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #0A3D33;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #f4f3f0;
  color: #0A3D33;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.admin-buttons {
  font-weight: 600;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #0A3D33;
  color: #f4f3f0;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.admin-buttons:hover {
  border: 2px solid #0A3D33;
  background-color:  #f4f3f0 ;
  color: #0A3D33;}
```

```js
const adressInput = document.querySelector(".adress-input");
const priceInput = document.querySelector(".price-input");
const numberOfFloorsInput = document.querySelector(".number-of-floors-input");
const floorInput = document.querySelector(".floor-input");
const roomsInput = document.querySelector(".rooms-input");
const areaInput = document.querySelector(".area-input");
const districtInput = document.querySelector(".district-input");
const imgNameInput = document.querySelector(".img-name-input");

const imgInput = document.querySelector('.input');
const containerImg = document.querySelector('.container-img');
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
let uploaded_image = "";


const cardArr = [];
const imgArrForPush = [];

 const onGetImg = () => {  
   
    const reader = new FileReader();
    var file = imgInput.files[0];

    reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
        uploaded_image = reader.result;

        imgArrForPush.push(uploaded_image);

    })

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    imgInput.value = "";
    
}


const onGetDataFromInput = () => {

    cardArr.push({
        imgNameInput:imgNameInput.value,
        inputData : {
            districtInput:districtInput.value,
            areaInput:areaInput.value,
            roomsInput:roomsInput.value,
            floorInput:floorInput.value,
            numberOfFloorsInput:numberOfFloorsInput.value,
            priceInput:priceInput.value,
            adressInput:adressInput.value
        },
        images:imgArrForPush
    });


    imgNameInput.value = "";
    districtInput.value = "";
    areaInput.value = "";
    roomsInput.value = "";
    floorInput.value = "";
    numberOfFloorsInput.value = "";
    priceInput.value = "";
    adressInput.value = "";
    imgInput.value = "";

    imgArrForPush.splice(0,imgArrForPush.length);

}

const redner = () => {
    container.innerHTML = "";

    cardArr.forEach(card => {
        console.log(card.images);
        container.innerHTML += ` <div class="card">

        <img src="${card.images[card.images.length - 1]}"/>
        
        <div class="card-info-container">
            <div class="card-info-sign-container">
                <div class="card-icon-container">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-location-dot"></i>
                </div>
                
                <p class="card-info-sign">${card.inputData.districtInput}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-info-sign-container">
                <div class="card-icon-container">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-layer-group"></i>
                </div>
                <p class="card-info-sign">${card.inputData.areaInput} м&sup2</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-info-sign-container">
                <div class="card-icon-container">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-bed"></i>
                </div>
                <p class="card-info-sign">${card.inputData.roomsInput}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-info-sign-container">
                <div class="card-icon-container">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-up"></i>
                </div>
                <p class="card-info-sign">${card.inputData.floorInput}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-info-price-container">
                <div class="icon-wrapper">
                    <div class="card-icon-container">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-dollar-sign"></i>
                    </div>
                    <p class="card-info-sign card-price">${card.inputData.priceInput}$</p>
                </div>
                <button class="card-button">Перейти</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>`
    })
}
```

What I want to get is this :

For example:

cardArr = [{
imgNameInput:"the_img_name",
districtInput:"the_district",
areaInput:"250",
roomsInput:"3",
floorInput:"5",
numberOfFloorsInput:"10",
priceInput:"30000",
adressInput:"the_adress",
images:["the_img_path_1","the_img_path_2","the_img_path_3"]
}]

Comment: Would it be possible to trim down your example to just two object properties? For example, `imgNameInput` and `images`? This would be done just to simplify things, and make it easier to test and debug - when I use your code as it is in your question, I get various console errors.

Comment: @FiddlingAway Yep , I did as you asked but did three properties instead of two because I think that array with images should be separate from inputs , and  I fixed several mistakes in my code

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want something [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/vkbc0wLg/)?

Comment: @FiddlingAway yeah, thanks,  that is what I wanted , but unfortunately it doesn't work if I want to render the image with this path in array . For example , I want to render one image but store several , and if I <img src="${card.images[0]}"/> it doesn't work. On the other hand if I write <img src="${uploaded_image}"/> it works as I expected. And I can't understand what's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the @FiddlingAway!!

```js
const adressInput = document.querySelector(".adress-input");
const priceInput = document.querySelector(".price-input");
const numberOfFloorsInput = document.querySelector(".number-of-floors-input");
const floorInput = document.querySelector(".floor-input");
const roomsInput = document.querySelector(".rooms-input");
const areaInput = document.querySelector(".area-input");
const districtInput = document.querySelector(".district-input");
const imgNameInput = document.querySelector(".img-name-input");

const imgInput = document.querySelector('.input');
const containerImg = document.querySelector('.container-img');
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
let uploaded_image = "";


const cardArr = [];
let imgArrForPush = [];

const onGetImg = () => {  
   
    const reader = new FileReader();
    var file = imgInput.files[0];


    reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
        uploaded_image = reader.result;
        imgArrForPush.push(uploaded_image);
        //imgArrForPush.push(uploaded_image);

    })

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    imgInput.value = "";
    
}


const onGetDataFromInput = () => {

    cardArr.push({
        imgNameInput:imgNameInput.value,
        inputData : {
            districtInput:districtInput.value,
            areaInput:areaInput.value,
            roomsInput:roomsInput.value,
            floorInput:floorInput.value,
            numberOfFloorsInput:numberOfFloorsInput.value,
            priceInput:priceInput.value,
            adressInput:adressInput.value
        },
        images:imgArrForPush
    });


    imgNameInput.value = "";
    districtInput.value = "";
    areaInput.value = "";
    roomsInput.value = "";
    floorInput.value = "";
    numberOfFloorsInput.value = "";
    priceInput.value = "";
    adressInput.value = "";
    imgInput.value = "";

      imgArrForPush = [];

}

const redner = () => {
    container.innerHTML = "";

    cardArr.forEach(card => {
        console.log(card.images);
        container.innerHTML += ` <div class="card">

        <img src="${card.images[0]}"/>
        
        <div class="card-info-container">
            <div class="card-info-sign-container">
                <div class="card-icon-container">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-location-dot"></i>
                </div>
                
                <p class="card-info-sign">${card.inputData.districtInput}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-info-sign-container">
                <div class="card-icon-container">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-layer-group"></i>
                </div>
                <p class="card-info-sign">${card.inputData.areaInput} м&sup2</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-info-sign-container">
                <div class="card-icon-container">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-bed"></i>
                </div>
                <p class="card-info-sign">${card.inputData.roomsInput}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-info-sign-container">
                <div class="card-icon-container">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-up"></i>
                </div>
                <p class="card-info-sign">${card.inputData.floorInput}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-info-price-container">
                <div class="icon-wrapper">
                    <div class="card-icon-container">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-dollar-sign"></i>
                    </div>
                    <p class="card-info-sign card-price">${card.inputData.priceInput}$</p>
                </div>
                <button class="card-button">Перейти</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>`
    })
}
```